# How to possible php codeIgniter file upload lager file size 1GB using update_batch and where condition working

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me. I am tried but not working this condition.
Like I am using:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'My title' ,
        'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
        'date' => 'My date 2'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Another title' ,
        'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
        'date' => 'Another date 2'
    )
);

$this->db->where('programe_id','1');
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

where condition not working...

Comment: So, what does the above code have to do with file uploads? You need to clarify your question.

Comment: ...specially since the above code is simply a copy/paste from the manual. What does _your_ code look like?

Comment: just i am using upload build in library. excel file upload this problem.
 update_batch working but where condition not working....

Comment: Define _"not working"_. Error message? Wrong result? Nothing happens? Computer caught on fire? I still don't get what your _file upload_ have to do with you _database update_? You need to update your question with _all_ the relevant code _and_ a detailed explanation what you're trying to achieve, what you expect  to happen and what _actually_ happens (including any error message you're getting).